# How to get a list of wifi networks in an Android App

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to include a list of WiFi networks in an Android App to allow the user to select one to connect a physical device to. In the past I have used `WiFiManager` class startscan & scanresults to do this. But startscan is now deprecated (and doesn't seem to work for me). I have looked around but can not seem to find any alternatives to this.

How can I get a list of WiFi networks without using deprecated api calls?

If the above is not possible can I search for a specific network - for example one that starts ABCD?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 9 (API level 28), accessing a list of available Wi-Fi networks without starting a scan is restricted for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: So If I start a scan I can do this still (WiFiManager > startscan)?

Comment: You should can.

Comment: It just seems odd that is startscan is the way to go why its depreciated and just controlled differently. However running a quick test is not returning any networks.